# Is it possible to know which server is being used for a WebRTC peer to peer connection - TURN or STUN server?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, turn

After a connection has been established using WebRTC is it possible to know whether TURN or STUN server is being used establish the connection.

PS - I am not using any third party libraries like Kurento for establishing WebRTC connection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the STUN server is always utilized (if a STUN address is provided by the app) as part of ICE procedure during candidate collection process. If one is not provided, a browser deduces its public address(es) during ICE Connectivity test process (called peer reflexive address).

Once ICE concludes successfully, it is possible to get the connected address via API call and can determine whether it is a TURN addr or not. If your q is whether the end user know it, then the answer depends on whether the app decide to inform the user or not. Usually apps do not. A determined user can find out by looking at chrome://webrtc-internals or equivalent.